# CAML Query to retrieve list item by title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, caml, .net

I'm trying to query for only this the item called Test1. I'm using this caml query but I'm returning all items in the list for some reason.

[image]

```
private static int GetlookUpId(List hrLookupList, string value, ClientContext ctx)
        {
            //caml for the list item
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            string camlQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">"+value+"</Value></Eq></Where>";
            query.ViewXml = camlQuery;
            var listItems = hrLookupList.GetItems(query);
            ctx.Load(listItems);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Why am i getting them all back instead of the one called Test1? value here is equal to "Test1".

Comment: string camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>"+value+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

Answer (score 4):

Query should be like

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Test1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: I'm now getting a "Cannot complete this action" with the camlquery being `string camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\"></Value>"+value+"</Eq></Where></Query></View>";`

Comment: Please refer my last edit. There was some mistakes that I have corrected.

Comment: you're a lifesaver

Comment: Good to know it helped. Happy coding!